# how to draw a disabled icon

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm finally getting around to adding icons to our pull down menus:

[image: menu clip]
In this image, you can see that everything but the highlighted line is okay.  The highlighted line is fine except for the icon, which is drawn in color, instead of grayed.

I'm basing my code off of a minimalist approach:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16529/Simple-Menus-That-Display-Icons-Minimalistic-Appro?msg=4166441#xx4166441xx

Basically, this only requires that I draw the icon, and I don't have to manage all aspects of a menu item using custom code.  Pretty nifty.

It works for our purposes except when selecting a disabled (grayed) menu item.
But when the menu item is grayed and selected, then the drawn icon appears as it would if it were enabled.  Wrong. :(

Yet the exact same drawing code works when the background is highlighted/selected.

**That leads me to believe that there is some stated contained entirely in the HDC that must control how the icon is appearing - since the following code works under all conditions but selected:**

```
::DrawIconEx(lpdis->hDC, lpdis->rcItem.left+0, lpdis->rcItem.top, pIcon->GetHandle(), pIcon->GetSize().cx, pIcon->GetSize().cy, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);
```

Does anyone know what state is encapsulated in the HDC that would control how DrawIconEx functions?  If I can replicate the HDC state during selected drawing as found when not-selected-drawing, I should be able to generate the grayed icons without resorting the 30-50 line implementations that manually gray-scale the icon in memory.

Comment: I don't know how this works, but the obvious way for Windows to do this would be to give you a memory DC backed by a greyscale bitmap.  Obviously it can't do this in the selected case because it needs to draw in colour.  You can check if it does do this using GetCurrentObject and GetObject.

Comment: You don't need owner draw to have glyphs on your menus. Windows can do it all for you.

Comment: How?!  Setting the checkmark images only allows monochrome glyphs.  Most techniques and discussions out there indicate that you must use owner draw (or custom windows), either of which can be extensive in terms of lines of code.  This is the minimum I could find that allows color icons.

Comment: Use the `hbmpItem` field of `MENUITEMINFO`. Support has been patchy. No support on Win2000. Works on XP. On Vista and up you are meant to put in a PARGB32 bitmap but then it just shines. That's the only reliable way to get good Vista/7 style menus with glyphs. The theme API custom drawing approach is almost impossible to get right. Have you noticed that your menus look very out of place on Vista/7? That's because you are custom drawing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
DrawState(...)
```

API function, with DSS_DISABLED flag, but I am not sure about the quality of the output.

Comment: IIRC the quality of DrawState is very poor.

Comment: ::DrawState(lpdis->hDC, NULL, NULL, (LPARAM)pIcon->GetHandle(), NULL, lpdis->rcItem.left, lpdis->rcItem.top, pIcon->GetSize().cx, pIcon->GetSize().cy, DST_ICON|DSS_UNION);

Comment: It's a fine solution for my purposes.  Much preferred over writing/testing a manual gray-scale implementation.

Comment: FYI - DSS_UNION gives a gray-text appearance, mildly odd.  DSS_DISABLED embosses the edges, which make the icon appear to shift or pop.  I played with the pen & brush & text & background colors, but in the end, DSS_DISABLED also uses the highlight color (blue) in various transparent places.  so DSS_UNION is as good as it gets for this technique.